# Receiving POST data in Rails 4 and reading request.body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post, routes

I want to send a POST request to a rails application and have it save and parse the request body in the database...

My route on the receiving end is currently setup as:

```
post '/request' => 'controller#receives_data'
```

when I post data to this controller I use:

```
def post_it
  connection.post(uri.path, "this is data", header_with_authkey)
end
```

My controller method that receives the post is setup as:

```
def receives_data
   log(request.body.read)
end
```

However I am getting a `422 error, unprocessable entity`, and the log file is always empty...

Are there specific headers I need to include to post this to a rails app? Are there specific configurations I need to include in my controller or routes?

Comment: What content type are you using in your request?

Comment: The only header I specify is my authorization token.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You'll need to set the following headers in your post.

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: Does the Net::HTTP post method always send the data as JSON data?

Comment: You should set Content-Type: header field for POST. If no Content-Type: field given, this method uses “application/x-www-form-urlencoded” by default. Read here -> http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-post

Comment: If that doesn't work, it could alternatively be due to this bug -> https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11402. Check the version you are using.

Answer (score 43):

```
request.raw_post
```

Read the request body. This is useful for web services that need to work with raw requests directly.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-raw_post